# Orders Sold per Day over Last 30 days

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need help. I want to fix this code. I have tried for hours. I want to get the "orders Sold per Day - Default date range: Last 30 days".

This is what the order collection looks like

```
{
    status: 'BEING_PREPARED',
    option: 'DELIVERY',
    driver: null,
    staffComment: '',
    driverComment: null,
    paymentMethod: null,
    etd: null,
    ptd: null,
    deliveryFees: 0,
    discount: 0,
    voucherId: null,
    orderItems: [[Object], [Object], [Object]],
    subtotal: 24.849999999999998,
    branch: ObjectId("5c98a67a2061ed07b45100e1"),
    datetime: ISODate("2019-04-06T17:11:43.171Z"),
    number: 1347,
}
```

This is what I have done so far.

```
router.route('/api/ordes')
        .get(function(req, res) {

            var result = connection.db.collection("orders").aggregate([{
                    $match: {
                        "datetime": {
                            $lte: (new Date((new Date()).getTime() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$group": {
                            _id: { 
                           "year":  { "$year": "$datetime" },
                           "month": { "$month": "$datetime" },
                           "day":   { "$dayOfMonth": "$datetime" }
                        },
                        totalValue: { $sum: "$subtotal" }
                    }
                }
            ]);
            result.toArray(function(err, doc) {
                console.log(doc);
                res.status(200).json(doc);

            });
        });
```

This is the results I got

```
[
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 7, "day": 2}, "totalValue": 3875.92
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 30}, "totalValue": 9594.92
    },
    {

        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 29}, "totalValue": 8820.369999999999
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 28}, "totalValue": 8881.76
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 27}, "totalValue": 4286.66
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 26}, "totalValue": 4716.66
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 25}, "totalValue": 3093.82
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 23}, "totalValue": 9905.26
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 22}, "totalValue": 10492.32
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 21}, "totalValue": 9261.52
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 20}, "totalValue": 3794.98
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 19}, "totalValue": 4191.64
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 17}, "totalValue": 3749.33
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 4}, "totalValue": 1915.72
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 6, "day": 2}, "totalValue": 5884.91
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 5, "day": 29}, "totalValue": 2784.5
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 5, "day": 28}, "totalValue": 1986.87
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 5, "day": 26}, "totalValue": 7209.74
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 5, "day": 24}, "totalValue": 5398.99
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 7, "day": 4}, "totalValue": 4256.6
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 5, "day": 23}, "totalValue": 2365.48
    },
    {
        "_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 5, "day": 22}, "totalValue": 2452.8199999999997
    }
]
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting, you need to elaborate the question a little bit. Where are you stuck. Do not expect people to find and guess !

Comment: I want to get the orders sold per day over the last 30 days.

Comment: Why not drop the `$group` stage if all you want is the orders?

Comment: Sorry I am trying to get orders sold per day with the day

Answer (score 0):

Keep the original structure and use the [$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) variable to keep the orders data:

```
connection.db.collection("orders").aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "datetime": {
                $lte: (new Date((new Date()).getTime() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            _id: {
                "year": {"$year": "$datetime"},
                "month": {"$month": "$datetime"},
                "day": {"$dayOfMonth": "$datetime"}
            },
            totalValue: {$sum: "$subtotal"},
            orders: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
        }
    }
]);
```

EDIT:

You can use the blow aggregation to get the desired result, due to the fact that we can't know the last date in the database then we have to first group all the collection.

I personally recommend you do not do this like this but split it into 2 steps, first query to find the max date. then you can use

```
{
        $match: {
            "datetime": {
                $lte: (new Date((maxDateFromCollection.getTime() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))
            }
        }
    }
```

To match and it will be a-lot more efficient when the scale gets larger.

```
connection.db.collection("orders").aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            _id: {
                "year": {"$year": "$datetime"},
                "month": {"$month": "$datetime"},
                "day": {"$dayOfMonth": "$datetime"}
            },
            totalValue: {$sum: "$subtotal"},
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "_id.year": -1,
            "_id.month": -1,
            "_id.day": -1,
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 30
    },
    // next steps are only necessary if days could be missing and we have less than 30 results.
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            orders: {$push: "$$ROOT"},
            maxDate: {$first: "$_id"}
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$orders"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {
                    $and: [ // same month if its months with 30 or less days. or day greater than 1.
                        {
                            $or: [
                                {
                                    "orders._id.day": {$gt: 1},
                                },
                                {
                                    "orders._id.month": {$in: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]}
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: ["$orders._id.year", "$maxDate.year"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: ["$orders._id.month", "$maxDate.month"]
                            }

                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    $and: [ // if day is 1 than no 31
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$orders._id.year", "$maxDate.year"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$orders._id.month", "$maxDate.month"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "orders._id.day": {$ne: 31}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {   // days from previous month
                    $and: [
                        {
                            "maxDate.month": {$in: [5, 7, 10, 12]}
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$orders._id.year", "$maxDate.year"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$orders._id.month", {$subtract: ["$maxDate.month", 1]}
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $gt: [
                                    "$orders._id.day", "$maxDate.day"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {   // days from previous month
                    $and: [
                        {
                            "maxDate.month": {$in: [2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11]}
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$orders._id.year", "$maxDate.year"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$orders._id.month", {$subtract: ["$maxDate.month", 1]}
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $gt: [
                                    "$orders._id.day", {$add: ["$maxDate.day", 1]}
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {   // days from previous month
                    $and: [
                        {
                            "maxDate.month": 3
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$orders._id.year", "$maxDate.year"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$orders._id.month", {$subtract: ["$maxDate.month", 1]}
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $gt: [
                                    "$orders._id.day", {$subtract: ["$maxDate.day", 2]}
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {   // days from previous month
                    $and: [
                        {
                            "maxDate.month": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "orders._id.month": 12
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$orders._id.year", {$subtract: ["$maxDate.year", 1]}
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $gt: [
                                    "$orders._id.day", {$add: ["$maxDate.day", 1]}
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$orders"

        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you but I am receiving wrong output. I am trying to total order value per day over the last 30 days. Default date range: Last 30 days.

Comment: maybe post an example of your required output as i seem to not understand what you want.

Comment: Okay I want to sum up all the orders for each day over last 30 days.  [{"_id":2019 /7/2},"totalValue":3875.92} for each day over the last 30 days. the problem I have is that it is returning a results of more than 30 days

Comment: Ah, just change the `$lte` to `$gte` then

Comment: then I get null.

Comment: then you have no data from the past 30 days in the database?

Comment: I am supposed to get the total of all orders for each day over last 30 days from the last document inserted into the orders collection

Comment: Yes you are getting it

Comment: how to I get the sum of Orders Sold per Day over Last 30 days from the last document inserted into the order collection?

Comment: I edited my answer and added a good solution, note i didn't consider gap year in case of missing days data.

Comment: Okay Thank you let me try it out

Comment: It returns null

Comment: i posted new syntax, try it, but again i recommend you split it into 2 calls instead of this aggregation

Comment: Okay I will try it. Thank you so much. I appreciate it.